# How can I improve my specific question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions, suggested-edits

[My question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4143185/900585)

I am here to understand how improve to formulate my question.

As matter of fact in the link I have tried to show my attempt and I have required as a question to check if my attempt is correct. I don't know if no answers are due to a bad formulation of a question...but if yes I am here to ask you how can I modify eventually my question! Thanks!

Comment: The question you linked to looks fine, you've even received to upvotes on it.  Please note that you should not worry about not receiving an answer to a post which is two hours young!  Users here all volunteer, but we have jobs, or some are students, etc., so that in the last two hours, likely not everyone qualified to answer it has yet seen it.  Be patient.  I can assure your question is fine.  Now we need to be patient so other users can answer it.  Some questions aren't answered until the next day, or 12 hours later...

Comment: ... But you have no need to panic; questions are not usually answered immediately.

Comment: Ah ok thanks! I wanted to know only if this was a matter of a bad formulation!

Comment: You did a fine job in your post! ;D

Comment: For what it's worth, [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback) chatroom is specifically for helping people improve their questions, etc.